# JAVA: Calculating the pushback from a beam weapon in 2D

Tags: java, physics

I am trying to make a game where the player has a laser weapon which he can shoot at objects to push them, or shoot at the floor/walls to move himself from place to place.
My problem is, I can't figure out how to make the pushback - the force that propels you to the opposite direction when you shoot, and neither the force that pushes other objects (although it would be easier once I know how to calculate the former). Can anybody help me?

The info I have:

```
Laser = startX, startY, endX, endY.
Player = x, y, width, height, xVel, yVel.
D = distance between the player and the laser end point.
```

How do I calculate the `xVel\yVel` difference?

Comment: Newton to the rescue! PushbackForce = -PushForce

Comment: lasers have very little push back force. They are not like projectile weapons in terms of push back.

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum#Conservation) is a good reference for a start...

Comment: @SJuan76 I know, but I need to find a way to calculate one of them :)

Comment: You're going to have to make up a force that makes sense for your game.  I'll start and say that one pulse propels an object (or you) 1 meter in 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the mass of the objects and the force of the projectile. 
You can extend a class or build an interface or you can attach those attributes to Laser or player and use it in the signature of the physics method.

Like the comments say you

> force=-opposingForce

Newton tells us Force= mass * acceleration.

You can use speed for accelration for simplicty.

to find the speed:

> Distance = Startway-Endway

For speed you have to use a time-tick  method that will count in intervals you may configure.

> speed = Distance * time

Now you can use the force to give negative speed to the opponents!